# ! [tab] shortcut not working with blade extention

Tags: html, phpstorm, laravel-blade, shortcut

I was making a new file using PhpStorm IDE in which I wanted some HTML. My file name was `welcome.blade.php`. When I tried using the `![tab]` shortcut to make an HTML skeleton, nothing happened. All that appeared was a `!` and a `tab` space.

I know that this shortcut only works on HTML and PHP files, so it seems that because of the `.blade` extension of Laravel, PhpStorm doesn't recognize it. I made a `welcome.php` file in the same directory, and the shortcut worked perfectly.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Works just fine here in my test project. 1) What IDE version do you have there? 2) Does it work in other `.blade.php` files (named differently)? 3) Do other Live Templates / Emmet stuff work? 4) How you file looks what IDE thinks of it) -- please show a full IDE screenshot with that file visible (Project View)  and file opened in the editor area. 4) Any custom plugins? 5) What about Vue plugin (it sometimes causes different kind of issues) -- try disabling it with IDE restart -- any different now?

Comment: I just tried changing the name of the file, and it worked! The name I tried using was reserved for something else I think, because every other name works. (afdmosngfdkasonf.blade.php works)

Comment: It's not reserved. It means that you have somehow (by mistake/unknowingly) misconfigured PhpStorm for such name. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` -- browse through file types (top list) and remove unwanted pattern once found -- that's the best I can say right now based on your limited info